# How to make executable file from R Project that developed in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

I desperately want to ask how to create an executable file from R Project that contains some R scripts in RStudio?
It doesn't matter that we have to install R first. It doesn't matter whether it .exe or .bat etc.

I have been made the GUI with tcltk and tcltk2 in R. So I just need to distribute it. Anyone have any solution? Please. It has to be done in 2 weeks.

Comment: I am not quite sure about your requirements: Do you look for a way to install your "R application" on different computers or want to hide the source code or want to create an icon the user can click on... Generally you can install your "R application" by just copying the source code folder somewhere on the target computer. To start your R code you just need to create a batch file that calls your main code, eg. `Rscript myApplication.R`. This requires R to be installed incl. the the required packages (which could be another requirement of your question: How to install dependent "runtimes")...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to distribute it as executable file in windows, i think you should develop it in .net framework, for example C# environment. and to bridge between R and C#, you can use a package called [R.Net](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/). R.Net is just a package that allows you to run R code via .net environment. you can find my R.net clustering code in my [github](https://github.com/blankon123/rdotnet-parsing)